# Spring Boot RestTemplate Slow Response

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

We're using Spring Boot + RestTemplate between the client and REST service (both are running locally on windows). I've measured the time of the service call, it was fine, but the time between the result is ready to be returned from the server and client gets the response is very slow.

```
ResponseEntity<PageResult<MyPOJO>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, typeRef);
    return  response;
```

The data is not large (around 50 records), it does not make sense to take 9 seconds to return the result back to the client. How do I troubleshoot which part takes the longest time? any performance tuning or configuration tips for RestTemplate?